# AMD64 ABI Function Calling Sequence for arguments of type __m256

Tags: x86-64, abi

I've been reading through this section for a while, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm on AMD64 ABI Draft 0.99.6, page 18, section `3.32 Parameter Passing` and theres the following text:

Arguments of type __m256 are split into four eightbyte chunks. The least significant one belongs to class SSE and all the others to class SSEUP.

I'm confused because it sounds like I use three SSEUP registers and only one SSE, but that seems wasteful of the other two SSE registers associated with the SSEUP. Am I misreading it? I probably won't even use this datatype, but I've been confused on this text for quite a while. Can someone give an example of how this would work? I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Page 18 just contains a list of definitions necessary for a later discussion of the algorithm used to pass the parameters of a function.

Particularly, the *SSE* class is always passed in a new *vector* register, the first available of `%xmm0-%xmm7`.
Note that these names refer to the lower 128-bit parts of the registers but its better to think of them in terms of variable size vector registers `%v0-%v7`.
The *SSEUP* class is passed in the next available 64-bit (eight-byte) of the *last* vector register used.

`__m256` is then passed, in processors that support AVX, using a single `%ymm` register: the lower 64 bits get the *SSE* class - and hence a new `%v0` register - while the other three 64 bits chunks get *SSEUP* thereby reusing the `%v0` register.

Here's the relevant quote from the document:

> 3. If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used, the registers
>      are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.
> 4. If the class is SSEUP, the eightbyte is passed in the next available eightbyte
>      chunk of the last used vector register.

The *SSEUP* class was introduced earlier in the ABI and it is still present today.
You can quickly consult the [Version 0.9](https://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf) to see the differences: the type `_m256` and `_m512` were not present for example.

For compiler that doesn't support the new ABI with the `_m256` type or for compilers that do support it but target processors with no AVX support, that type is usually [an aggregate of two `_m128`](https://godbolt.org/g/Ql3bfP) and thus by the rules described later (particularly the post-merge rules) it is passed in memory:

> 1. If the size of an object is larger than two eightbytes, or in C++, is a nonPOD structure or union type, or contains unaligned fields, it has class
>      MEMORY.
>
> <sup>For compilers using the old ABI</sup>
>
> If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eightbyte
>   isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument
>   is passed in memory.
>
> <sup>For compilers using the new ABI</sup>

The standard is admittedly confusing mostly due to the need to address backward compatibility, the *SSE* and *SSEUP* classifications are handy classifications in an architecture where the vector registers keep widening and broad range of different sizes are already present out there.